# Is it linearly independent?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

*E={(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1),(1,1,1),(1,1,0)}*

Is any three vectors of E are linearly independent?

It is clear that E is linearly dependent and any 4 vectors of E are linearly dependent. My book says that the answer of the above question is affirmative. But I think the last three vectors of the set is not linearly independent.

Answer (score 1):

*Of course* that the last three vectors are linearly dependent! After all, $(1,1,1)=(0,0,1)+(1,1,0)$.

Comment: New topic. Very confused sir. Thanks for the help.